# Android 4.1 RelativeLayout and positioning ads(mmedia) on bottom

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have an issue with positioning Millenial Media(http://mmedia.com/) ads on bottom of the screen. Sometimes it works, but sometimes the ad jumps to the center of the screen for no reason. Other times the ad just starts out at that position. Sometimes the ad just rapidly jumps between the middle and bottom position.

I've tried a number of relative positions, options and configs but nothing makes it work properly.

The ad has AlignParentBottom property and I am not sure if this is just an issue with MMedia sdk or something else.

This only started happening in the latest release of the SDK. Does anyone use MMedia and can shed some light on positioning ads to bottom of the screen?

I use Google Nexus with Android 4.1.

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <GameView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
            android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you please show us the axml you are using?

Comment: Try adding: `android:layout_below="@+id/list"` to the MMAdView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was an issue with their system. Got this reply:

> Thanks for reaching out to Millennial Media! This is a really annoying known issue that  seems to only happen on certain high-resolution devices running the latest version of  Android. More specifically, the Android OS changed some mechanics of their WebView object that ends up rendering our HTML-based creatives incorrectly. This is presently priority one. If there are specific creatives that seem to be recurring, we could block the campaigns associated with those.
>
> I can't give you an exact date on the fix, but it's creating a flurry of activity, so I'm hoping by the end of the week, all of our HTML templates will be updated. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

I had me too "very interesting" behaviour with a 3rd party component.
I have solved with embedding him in a container ( LinearLayout as I remember), so my suggestion is to add the `com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView` to a  `LinearLayout` and that add to `RelativeLayout`. I can't explain why is worked for me and can't explain why isn't worked without wrapper as I wanted, but that was the solution.

I hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried it but nothing changed, same issue. The ad just jumps to the center of the screen.